# How to validate dynamically generated field from this javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
currentg1 = 1; // This is input files added by default.
maxg1 = 5;
ming1 = 1;
contor = 3;
contor1 = 4;
valuek = 2;
function g1_app_child(){
if(currentg1<maxg1)
{
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = 'divfiles'+currentg1;
    /*div.style.width = "100px";
    div.style.height = "100px";
    div.style.background = "red";
    div.style.color = "white";*/
    div.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="g1_delchild()">Remove websites</a><br><table><tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on'+contor+'" value="Keywords" class="special">Keywords: </td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os'+contor+'" maxlength="200" id="keywords" class="special">ex: seo services</td></tr><tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on'+contor1+'" value="Website" class="special">Website: </td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os'+contor1+'" maxlength="200" id="website" class="special">ex: seoadsem.com</td></tr><input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="'+valuek+'"></table>';
    document.getElementById('outer_div').appendChild(div);
currentg1++;
valuek++;
    if (contor%2) {
        contor1++ == contor++ + 1;
    }
    else {
        contor++;
    }
contor++;
contor1++;
    return false;
}
else
{
    alert('Maximum '+maxg1+' 5 websites are allowed');
    return false;
}
}

function g1_delchild()
{
if(currentg1>ming1)
{
    cnt = currentg1-1;
    element = document.getElementById('divfiles'+cnt);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    currentg1--;
    return false;
}
else
{
    alert('Minimum '+ming1+' Website Allowed');
    return false;
}
}

function validateForm() {
"use strict";
/*global document: false */
/*jshint sub:true*/
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
var w = document.forms.myPayPal.os0.value;
var x = document.getElementById('keywords').value;
var y = document.getElementById('website').value
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Please input keywords");
    document.getElementById('keywords').focus() 
    return false;
}
if (y == null || y == "") {
    alert("Please input website");
    document.getElementById('website').focus() 
    return false;
}
if (w === "0") {
    alert("You must agree to the terms of service");
    return false;
}

}
```

When i try it, it validates only the initial fields.
When it is starting to validate it, doesn't go through when i click more fields and click submit. Here is the test page: http://www.seoadsem.com/full-SEO-report-for-your-website-test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have only one element with the same id on the page when you use `getElementById` (it will select the first one) and you should not use more then one (use class instead). But you can still validate your current script if you use:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#keywords')).forEach(function(keyword) {
    // validate keyword here
});
```

it will select all elements with id = keywords

Comment: [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#keywords')).forEach(function(keyword) {
    if (isNaN(keyword.value)== null || keyword.value == "") {
        alert("Please input keywords");
        document.getElementById('keywords').focus(); 
        return false;
    }
}); Tried this and did not work. Sorry i am a noob.

Comment: It's working well for keywords, but when i try to do it for websites doesn't work, also terms of services validation doesn't work anymore. http://jsfiddle.net/tT7xd/3/

Comment: @Adrian because you have `return` before `[].slice.call(websites)` so that code is not executed, put it at the end. http://jsfiddle.net/tT7xd/4/